# How can I publish in the play store?

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I have been working to make an app for android, and I finally done. I have no idea what I have to do to publish my app in the play store. Google asked me a license key, but I don't know how to do this. I have completed my android app and it works well too. How can I solve this problem?

I have a developer account in Google Play, and I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you signed your app yet?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a signed .apk file

[Create signed apk file](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) will help you to create signed apk.

[publish application in playstore](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html)

**Creating signed apk**

```
First Step
```

[image]

```
Second Step
```

[image]

in your case you need to create new keystore ,press `Create new`

```
Step Three
```

[image]

```
Step Four
```

[image]
   select a file path for your new key store and give a name

```
Step Five
```

[image]

Fill all the fields,then press ok

```
Step Six
```

[image]

Press next

```
Step Seven
```

[image]

give master password ,then press ok,it will generate a signed apk for you.

Comment: very thanks! As I am a beginner in developing for android, and I don't know how to create a signed  .apk file, I am grateful for these links, I am going to search many tutorials, do you have any?

Comment: @victorcd check my answer

Comment: what software are you using in this tutorial?

Comment: @victorcd Android Studio

Comment: I am sorry again, I installed android studio, and I can't do the first step. I have an apk file compiled by buildozer, writed in kivy. As I don't know android studio, I think (probably I am wrong )by this way I am going to begin another apk project. I don't know, but can I generate a signed apk for my project even I did it on kivy and buildozer? Very thanks @Clifford